Cordova get a net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED error during OAuth redirection back to cordova
I've got a cordova app. At some point within the app users can login using MS B2C oauth. I've set the config.xml to allow the app to redirect to the MS OAuth site within the app and then redirect back to https://localhost/ as that's how the cordova app is serving up the content internally.
I'm hitting a problem that when the oauth system redirects back to localhost i'm getting an net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED and the app just closes.
Why would the internal website shutdown just because I've navigated to the list of allow-navigation? I've also, just for good measure added 

The only thing I can think to add to this is it's a 302 response, not a hyperlink activation. i say that as I can go to the oauth site and then use document.location in a console window and don't get the error.

The content is not served via http but https
